# If statement for two checkboxes are checked problem

Tags: java, android, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a code that states that if one checkbox is checked the second one can not be checked at the same time.
I have one checkbox called dayShift and another called nightShift.
If I am checking nightShift and THEN dayShift the code works as I expected. But if I check dayShift first and THEN nightShift, the code does not apply.

```
public void days(View view) {
    CheckBox nightShift_check = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.nightShift);
    CheckBox dayShift_check = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.dayShift);
    if (nightShift_check.isChecked() && dayShift_check.isChecked())
    {
        nightShift_check.setChecked(false);
        dayShift_check.setChecked(false);
        Toast.makeText(mainApplication.this,"Error message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `RadioButton`?

Comment: add whole code of your requirement which is working and which is not working

Comment: Is the method days() a listener of one or both checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to perform different logic for that you could use `RadioButton` so there can't be two statements true at the same time.

Otherwise you could add something that is called `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on your `CheckBox` and **uncheck them both if they both are checked** for example:

```
dayShift_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked && nightShift_check.isChecked()) {
            dayShift_check.setChecked(false);
            nightShift_check.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});
```

But I still strongly recommend you to use `RadioButton` if you need to choose from two, as  @NileshRathod mentioned above in comment section.
If you need to choose one option from more you probably want to use `RadioGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a listener on your CheckBox to get the state at each click :

```
nightShift_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            dayShift_check.setChecked(!isChecked);
        }
    });

dayShift_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            nightShift_check.setChecked(!isChecked);
        }
    });
```

When one have a state the other have the opposite state.
Hope it's help.